# UK settlement visa reapplication

Tags: united-kingdom

I applied for a uk settlement visa and it was refused, can I just ignore the appeal as they say it can take up to a year for the hearing and if I have to reapply again or how long do I have to wait for before I apply again ?.

Comment: What happened to my comment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may ignore the refusal and proceed with a fresh application.  And you do not need to wait, you can apply again right now.

But I always recommend not to do it immediately.  A refusal needs to be carefully examined because if you apply right away with the same stuff, they will refuse again and matters will be worse.

Overall, you should pause for a while and spend time getting better stuff to show them.  But of course if the refusal is straightforward nothing prevents your applying the day after.